# Unity ad does not show

Tags: unity, c#, advertisements, unity-ads

I have imported the advertisement package from the package manager, turned the ads service on, and added a script:

```
string gameId = "correctGameId";
bool testAds = true;
void Start(){
    Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testAds);
}

void Click (){
    if(Advertisement.isInitialised){
          Advertisement.Show();
    }
}
```

This Click function is called from a button's OnClick event.

Every time I play in the editor and click the button, nothing happens.

How can I make my advertisement show?

Comment: Do you see any output in your console log? Have you verified that the Click method is executing as expected? What value do you get from `Advertisement.isInitialised` inside that method?

Comment: No, no output in the console...... Also the button click function is executed properly......

Comment: And the answer to my third question? Don't forget to document this information in your question so we can clear out unneeded comments.

Comment: False; from isInitialised; Always;

Comment: There we go. Next we'll need to figure out why the advertisements aren't initializing. How have you configured your ads so far?

Comment: First i imported advertisement package...Then i opened services panel and enabled ads, and test mode.......Then i visited the project homepage and copied the app id.......and added the script.....Is this what you are askin for